# Not able to enter any text in ckeditor after showing it in modal

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm displaying ckeditor on button click in modal for user to input data in it but some times after ckeditor is displayed user is not able to enter anything in text box.

This is the HTML code :

```
<input type="button" class="btn" id="addsubcatpost" value="Add new post" ng-click="showsubcatpost()">

<textarea name="subcateditor" ng-model="cat_postcontent" id="subcateditor" rows="10" cols="80">{{postcontent}}</textarea>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('subcateditor', {
        toolbarGroups: [
            {"name": "styles", "groups": ["styles"]},
            {"name": "paragraph", "groups": ["list", "align"]},
            {"name": "basicstyles", "groups": ["basicstyles"]},
            {"name": 'insert', "groups": ['addImage']}
        ],
        removeButtons: 'Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Anchor,Styles,Specialchar,Format,Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe,addFile',                                                filebrowserUploadUrl: '/admin/categorymanagement/uploadckeditorimages'
    });
</script>
```

This is the js file :

```
$scope.showsubcatpost = function() {
  $scope.cat_title = '';
  CKEDITOR.instances['subcateditor'].setData('');
  $(".urlinks").val('');
  $(".selector-wrapper").html('');
  $(".attached-files").hide();
  $('.image-attachment-preview').html('');
  $('.document-attachment-preview').html('');
  $('.weblink-attachment-preview').html('');
  $('.gdocs-attachment-preview').html('');
  $('.video-attachment-preview').html('');
  $("#addnewsubcatpost").toggle();
  $(".hidediv").hide();
};
```

Screenshot of the modal

[image: Screenshot of the modal.]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `tabindex` attribute from the modal container did the trick for me.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6996

Comment: issue occurs sometimes.